# Compiling ARM .s for iPhone on Mac / Windows

Tags: ios, assembly, arm

I am new to this and here is what I want to do -

1. Create simple programs - loops, counters etc. using ARMv7 assembly
2. I want to be able to compile them on the Mac / Win / Linux for running on the iPhone
3. I have a jailbroken iPhone so I can upload the file there, sign it with ldid and run it

Can someone please point me to how I can do this with freely available tools?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm left wondering what you're trying to achieve here - is it to learn developing in ARM assembler?  Do you want to write iOS applications?

No sane person writes complete applications in assembler these days - they use high level languages - and in a few restricted cases optimize in assembler.  This is a very specialist and useful skill to have.

Using a complete C program as a surrogate host is good way to start. Create yourself a simple Hello world program in C which calls an (almost) empty function.

You can (mostly) get this to work using XCode (you need install the optional command-line tools).  All but the final linking stage for ARM works using `clang`.  This is obviously MacOSX only.

A better alternative for this kind of experimentation is an ARM Linux system where you're not fighting against the locked down environment of iOS. The [Raspberry Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org) is perfect for the job.    You'll need a cross-compiling toolchain for ARMv7 - of which there are plenty. If using Ubuntu, there are pre-built packages readily available.

`Main.c`

```
#include<stdio.h>

extern void func();

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    func();
}
```

and `func.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func()
{
    printf("In func()\n");
}
```

Compile both for your host environment and run it to see it works:

`gcc main.c func.c`
`./a.out'

Now compile for your target environment.  The precise name of the cross-compiling tools varies depending what you installed (mine is `arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-gcc`)

`arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-gcc main.c func.c`

Copy to your target, and prove it works.

Now you can start to write some assembler. Get `gcc` to produce ARM assembler for our victim file `func.c` - this results in a file `func.s`

`arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-gcc func.c -s`

:

```
    .cpu arm7tdmi-s
.fpu softvfp
.eabi_attribute 20, 1
.eabi_attribute 21, 1
.eabi_attribute 23, 3
.eabi_attribute 24, 1
.eabi_attribute 25, 1
.eabi_attribute 26, 2
.eabi_attribute 30, 6
.eabi_attribute 18, 4
.file   "func.c"
.section    .rodata
.align  2
.LC0:
.ascii  "In func()\000"
.text
.align  2
.global func
.type   func, %function
func:
@ Function supports interworking.
@ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 0
@ frame_needed = 1, uses_anonymous_args = 0
stmfd   sp!, {fp, lr}
add fp, sp, #4
ldr r0, .L2
bl  puts
sub sp, fp, #4
ldmfd   sp!, {fp, lr}
bx  lr
.L3:
.align  2
.L2:
.word   .LC0
.size   func, .-func 
.ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.5.4 20120305 (prerelease)"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",%progbits
```

You can see here that between label `func:` and `.L3` is the business end of `func()` - and it's almost all function prologue and epilogue. You'll want to check out the [ARM Procedure Call Standard](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042d/IHI0042D_aapcs.pdf) to understand what these are and for guidance on which registers to use.

Once you've done your edits, compile the whole thing again with GCC

`arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-gcc main.c func.s`

...and test it.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I am doing this to learn ASM on the iPhone. So basically what I am looking for is if I need to write a full Hello World program in ARMv7 asm, how would I do it?

Comment: Disassemble `main.c` - that is pretty much your minimal Hello World application.  It will, incidentally, be almost exactly the same under Linux.  

You obviously can't run console applications directly under iOS - although you will be able to do it from a SSH connection to a jail-broken device. 

If what you have in mind is writing graphical Hello World app against UIKit, you have a tough challenge ahead of you!